# Tool for converting a browser specific CSS to cross browser CSS

Tags: css, cross-browser

One of my development teams have written a couple CSS files that work flawlessly with IE. However, the UI is all messed up when rendered on other browsers.

Is there a tool that can take these CSS files and convert them into cross browser version? Unfortunately, these CSS files are too large and the expertise desirable to cook cross browser CSS and test it is lacking in the team at present.

The most recent versions of all prominent browsers need to be supported.

Answer (score 3):

No, because that would require a tool to understand your design intent and then fix it. If it was so easy to create cross browser compatible css by just using a magic tool we would all be using it.

Usually I see this done the other way around. Get it to work in all browsers and then hack in fixes to IE. My guess is that a few simple simple things are grossly affecting the layout. I would fix it for a more standards compliant browser like Firefox and then hack in fixes to old versions of IE as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Prefixr](http://prefixr.com/index.php). It did help me with some CrossBrowser issues, but I programmed for Chrome. Don't know how great the compatibility is the other way around.